Pcf Control(Dialog) Opening in new tab instead of same tab Dynamics 365
Image Attached  I have created a dialog pcf control and i want to trigger it on click of a button in the ribbon in the view page in dynamics .Below is my code when i click on the button its opening the control in new tab but it should open as overlay/dialog in the same view. please let me know where i am going wrong.I have attached the image of the pcf dialog
function LaunchControl() {
    // Centered Dialog
    var pageInput = {
      pageType: "control",
      controlName: "bonj_pcfControls.DialogControl",
    
    };
    var navigationOptions = {
      target: 2,
      position: 1,
      width: { value: 50, unit: "%" },
      title: "Time Off Request",
    };
    Xrm.Navigation.navigateTo(pageInput, navigationOptions)
      .then(function () {
        // Called when the dialog closes
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        // Handle error
      });
  }

I have tried changing the target and position values but no use .

Using Xrm.Navigation.navigateTo() for PCF controls is not supported. Still, on this blog post you may find a fix.
Another approach could be to bind your PCF control to an attribute and use that to trigger it. The control can then handle things the way you like.

But i guess this approach will not work  if we want to trigger pcf on views
